# Cant get my SQL to do what i want. Want it to return data new data after a given ID

Tags: php, mysql

I simply want to pass in an ID number (primary key) and get back any entries that were added since that ID. The ID increments for every entry so this should be a safe way to get new entries for the client.

But i am getting an error string back to my client

```
18Error retrieving scores You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that  corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id>18 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0,100' at line 1
```

I've been messing about with changing how its trying this and changing the query so it might be really messed up now. But anyways my code follows:

```
$table = "highscores";

// Initialization
$conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $conn);

// Error checking
if(!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect ' . mysql_error());
}

$type   = isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : "global";
$offset = isset($_GET['offset']) ? $_GET['offset'] : "0";
$count  = isset($_GET['count']) ? $_GET['count'] : "100";
$sort   = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : "id ASC";

// Localize the GET variables
$udid  = isset($_GET['udid']) ? $_GET['udid'] : "";
$name  = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name']  : "";
$clubname  = isset($_GET['clubname']) ? $_GET['clubname']  : "";
$theid  = isset($_GET['theid']) ? $_GET['theid']  : ""; 


// Protect against sql injections
$type   = mysql_real_escape_string($type);
$offset = mysql_real_escape_string($offset);
$count  = mysql_real_escape_string($count);
$sort   = mysql_real_escape_string($sort);
$udid   = mysql_real_escape_string($udid);
$name   = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$clubname   = mysql_real_escape_string($clubname);
$theid   = mysql_real_escape_string($theid);

    echo $theid;

// Build the sql query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ";
//$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id>$theid ";

switch($type) {
    case "global":
        $sql .= "1 ";
        break;
    case "device":
        $sql .= "udid = '$udid' ";
        break;
    case "name":
        $sql .= "name = '$name' ";
        break;
    case "clubname":
        $sql .= "clubname = '$clubname' ";
        break;
}

$sql .= "id>$theid ";
$sql .= "ORDER BY $sort ";
$sql .= "LIMIT $offset,$count ";

$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);

if(!$result) {
    die("Error retrieving scores " . mysql_error());
}
//echo $result;
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($conn);
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Can anybody put me on the right track to getting this to work please?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Comment: What is the resulting SQL query string?  i.e. what do you get when you `echo $sql`?

Comment: What is the exact query? (As in, what does `$sql` contain when your code reaches the `die()` statement?)

Comment: If any of those cases in your switch match, then you're going to end up with invalid sql as there's no boolean operator (and/or) joining the switch()-induced logic and the always-there `id>$theid`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate the advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll always have 2 conditions in your where clause, but there's an OR or AND missing between the two...  For one of the possible paths through the code this is what gets offered to the server:

```
SELECT * FROM $table 
WHERE udid = '$udid' id>$theid ORDER BY $sort LIMIT $offset,$count
```

but it should be something like

```
SELECT * FROM $table 
WHERE udid = '$udid' AND id>$theid ORDER BY $sort LIMIT $offset,$count
```

But as a general remark, Oli and Arjan's suggestions are excellent advice, a simple

```
echo $sql
```

can be very enlightening.

Comment: +1.  To the original poster, it's a good idea to get the entire query and send it directly to the server to test it.  MySQL will generally give easier to debug error messages if your query has line-breaks in it too.